# Hook state values are not accecesible in onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a form component, which has its own inputfields component, and used antd for designing, but while using hook state I faced some problems regarding accessing the values of hook states.

I made these input fields using `state[login]` passing them to my form component and the form component is rendering them using `map` function.

But, I am not able to access them in the `onclick` function.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Form from "../../Components/Form/Form";
import Layout, { Content } from "antd/lib/layout/layout";
import { Card } from "antd";
import "./login.css";
    
const Fun = (props) => {
  const [semail, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [spass, setpass] = useState("");

  const handleEmail = (event) => {
    setEmail(event.target.value);
  };
  const handlePass = (event) => {
    setpass(event.target.value);
    console.log("val", event.target.value);
  };
  console.log("Email and password is", semail, spass); ///but here they are

  const handleButton = () => {
    ///the hook state values are not accesible in this function
    console.log("Email and password is", semail, spass);
  };
  ///why is this happening and how can i access them in the onclick function
  ////I made these input fields using state[login] passing them to my form compnent and the form  component is rendreing them using map function....
  const [login] = useState({
    log: [
      {
        type: "Inputfield",
        name: "email",
        label: "Your-Email",
        placeholder: "Enter your Email",
        onChange: handleEmail,
        rules: [
          {
            type: "email",
            message: "The input is not valid E-mail!",
          },
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your E-mail!",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        type: "Inputfield",
        name: "password",
        label: "Password",
        placeholder: "Enter your Password",
        onChange: handlePass,
        rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please input your Password!" }],
      },
      {
        type: "Button",

        variant: "primary",
        size: "default",
        placeholder: "Login",
        onClick: handleButton,
      },
    ],
  });
    
  return (
    ///and here i am returning my inputfiels by passing them as props to my custom built  components
    <div>
      <Layout className="container">
        <Card className="lala">
          <p>
            <Form print={login.log} />
          </p>
        </Card>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Fun;
```

Comment: There are many issues with this example. Please may you correct them and make sure it is a [mcve]?

Comment: Try changing: `const handleButton() {` to `const handleButton = () => {`